# Laravel: Dependency injection and static custom method for all my models

Tags: php, laravel

I created a helper class for searching and filtering my laravel models (method uses tntsearch and a custom scope), currently it works all right but I want to make some improvements to it, sadly it's proving difficult to achieve what I want:

What I want to improve:

1) Being able to call search method statically on all my laravel models, like this:

```
Model::search();
```

Currently I have to instantiate the class and call the method like:

```
 $results = $searchHelper->search($request, $filters);
```

2)Right now I also have to pass two arguments to constructor, in my class I try dependency injection in construct magic method but I still have to pass request and filters as arguments...

How it looks in my controller:

```
public function search(Request $request, QueryFilters $filters)
    {
        $search = new Search($request, $filters);


        $posts = $search->search('Post', ['postcategory', 'author', 'favorites']);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Encontramos unas coincidencias',
            'posts' => $posts,
        ], 200);   
    }
```

My helper class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Filters\QueryFilters;
use App\Filters\Filterable;


class Search
{

    public $request;
    public $filters;

    public function __construct(Request $request, QueryFilters $filters)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->filters = $filters;
    }

    public function search( $model, $relationships = [] )
    {
        $model = app("App\Models\".$model."); 

        $results = $model::search($this->request->input('search'), '')->get(); 

        if(!$results->isEmpty())
        {
            $ids = implode(',', $results->pluck('id')->toArray());
            $filters->merge(['whereIn' => $ids]);    
        }

        $results = $model::filter($this->filters)->with($relationships)->paginate(10);

        return $results; 
    }


}
```

I want to call the method like this, NO passing arguments to constructor (DI should handle that), call method STATICALLY

```
Appointments::search();
```

Comment: What is `QueryFilters`? Where it comes from?

Comment: it's another helper class, it takes request object and builds a query for each GET param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `Searchable` trait (instead of your `Search` class) like this:

```php
trait Searchable
{
    public static function search($relationships = [])
    {
        //You may use the `resolve` method to resolve a class instance.
        $request = resolve(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class);
        //or $request = request();
        $filters = resolve(\App\Filters\QueryFilters::class);

        //rename the other `search` function on your model to `doSearch` to resolve conflicts
        $results = self::doSearch($request->input('search'), '')->get();
        //or using request helper function
        //$results = self::doSearch(request('search'), '')->get(); 

        if(!$results->isEmpty())
        {
            $ids = implode(',', $results->pluck('id')->toArray());
            $filters->merge(['whereIn' => $ids]);    
        }

        $results = self::filter($filters)->with($relationships)->paginate(10);

        return $results; 
    }

}
```

and implement this `Searchable` contract on your Eloquent model:

```php
class Appointment extends Model
{
    use Searchable;

    //...
}
```

now you can call:

```
Appointment::search();
```

Comment: gonna get a 'non-static method should not be called statically ...'

Comment: @lagbox Thanks, made the function static and renamed the other `search` function to `doSearch` to resolve conflicts.

Comment: this is looking good but I get "Using $this when not in object context"

Comment: never mind I fixed it by using self instead, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method to available to all models, you can create a new model with that method. Then extends every model you want search to be available in from that new model.